# Jenkins pipeline script from SCM invalid credentials

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I get the error shown below when configuring my pipeline
[image]

The github-pat credential is a username password credential with my username and a personal access token.

I have confirmed my username and access token are correct via command line, inside a jenkins pipeline script, and using them in a multibranch pipeline.  It only fails when trying to configure a single branch pipeline.

Putting the username and access token inside the url also works (in the form https://username:password@my-github-server/org/repo.git), but that obviously exposes my token.